# "Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error

Tags: .net, azure, powershell

Below is the code in my custom script extension

```
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile $env:C:\temp\azcopy.zip
```

when I run my custom script extension , I am getting below error

```
"Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
```

Any help on how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 5):

That error is pretty specific, which makes this potentially an environmental issue on your host or in your enterprise environment, as the code you posted, should/does work as-is.

```
# Tested on a few lab hosts
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile $env:C:\temp\azcopy.zip -Verbose
Get-ChildItem C:\temp

# Results
<#
VERBOSE: GET https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows with 0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 9317519-byte response of content-type application/zip


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                   
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                   
-a----         9/11/2020   8:45 PM        9317519 azcopy.zip                                             
#>
```

Yet you really only need this at the top of your code.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

You can get more about the error by running the code, let the error happen and then using

```
$Error[0] | Format-List -Force
```

You can also find out more by using the [Trace-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7) cmdlet.

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile $env:C:\temp\azcopy.zip
} -PSHost
# Results
<#
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Invoke-WebRequest]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows] to parameter [Uri]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Uri]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.String to System.Uri
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             CONVERT arg type to param type using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             CONVERT SUCCESSFUL using LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo: [https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows] to param [Uri] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [\temp\azcopy.zip] to parameter [OutFile]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [\temp\azcopy.zip] to param [OutFile] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Invoke-WebRequest]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Invoke-WebRequest]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
#>
```

When trying to hit remote resources, it best to test for the liveliness/connection before taking action. Normally that's a Test-Connection/Test-NetConection thing, but in your case, one of the Invoke-* cmdlets would be more prudent.

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows' -UseBasicParsing

```
# Results
<#
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {80, 75, 3, 4...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-MD5: HjZjoPa87mg1bK4eVQqASQ==
                    x-ms-request-id: aa4341fb-e01e-00a6-0c94-810077000000
                    x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
                    x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
                    x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
                    Connect...
Headers           : {[Content-MD5, HjZjoPa87mg1bK4eVQqASQ==], [x-ms-request-id, aa4341fb-e01e-00a6-0c94-810077000000], [x-ms-version, 2009-09-19], 
                    [x-ms-lease-status, unlocked]...}
RawContentLength  : 9317519
#>
```

See also this [article](https://blog.darrenjrobinson.com/powershell-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-occurred-on-a-send/).

Comment: So basically are you saying to run Invoke-WebRequest by adding -UseBasicParsing ? Something as below in my Custom script extension

$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows' -UseBasicParsing

Comment: Nope. As you can see from my tested code of your post it works. So, again, something is blocking/dropping you from your host. This only it has to do with the results returned. [By default, script code in the web page may be run when the page is being parsed to populate the ParsedHtml property. Use the -UseBasicParsing switch to suppress this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1). This is no longer needed when using PowerShell Core since that is its default.

Comment: Hmm ok, Is there a way/work around that I can do to achieve this ? I am not sure what is blocking it , But I need to have azcopy to be copied to my server using custom script extension. 

Any suggestion would be helpful.

FYI, I tried again by updating my script as below
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-windows -OutFile $env:C:\temp\azcopy.zip

I got the same error as before

Comment: You can't work around a network block/drop. You need to find out why you are being blocked/dropped and this is a conversation with your network team. Changing the script does nothing to deal with a network block/drop.